# Find probability distribution

Tags: probability

Cumulative distribution function $F_\xi(x)$ continuous at $0$. Find the probability distribution random variable

$
\eta = \begin{cases}
\frac \xi {|\xi|},&\xi \neq 0,\\
1,&\xi = 0.
\end{cases}
$

What property is necessary? Maybe that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}p_k=1$? But how I can use it...

Comment: $$\Pr[ \eta = 1] = \Pr[\xi \ge 0]$$ and $$\Pr[\eta = -1] = \Pr[\xi < 0].$$

Comment: @heropup $\Pr[\xi \ge 0]=\Pr[\xi < 0]=0.5$ Is it right?

Comment: No, that information is not supplied in the content of your question.  We don't know if it is equally likely that $\xi$ is negative or nonnegative.  Many random variables do not possess such a property; e.g., a normal distribution with mean $1$ will be more likely to be positive than negative.